# ASM: MethodVisitor's methods are not called by the ClassReader

Tags: java, netbeans, bytecode, static-analysis, java-bytecode-asm

I am writing a small tool to perform static analysis of bytecode using ASM 5. I give my input Java class to a ClassReader which triggers events of a custom ClassVisitor. My ClassVisitor overrides `visitMethod` to return my custom MethodVisitor if certain conditions are met, and `null` if they are not.

The problem is, the ClassReader never invokes the MethodVisitor's methods; I debugged it with NetBeans and i saw that the visitor is correctly returned (it is not `null`) but still the execution never enters the `visitMethodInsn` even though there *are* method instruction in the classes I'm using for testing.

I have used ASM before, but this is the first time i encounter this problem.

Here is my code for `MyClassVisitor.visitMethod`:

```
@Override
public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
    InvokeFinder visitor;
    if(condition.isMet()) {
        visitor = new InvokeFinder(api);
        visitor.doStuff();
    } else {
        visitor = null;
    }
    return visitor;
}
```

Here the code of `InvokeFinder`, which is never entered during execution:

```
public class InvokeFinder extends MethodVisitor {

    public InvokeFinder(int api) {
        super(api);
    }

    void unrelatedMethod(String parameter) {
        doStuff(parameter);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc) {
        switch (opcode) {
            case Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL:
            case Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL:
            case Opcodes.INVOKEDYNAMIC:
                doSomething();
                break;
            case Opcodes.INVOKEINTERFACE:
                doSomethingElse();
                break;
            case Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC:
                doSomethingDifferentAgain();
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally this is the class I'm testing on (this is not meant to be ever executed, its sole purpose is to be compiled and then analyzed by my tool):

```
public class MyTestClass{

  public MyTestClass(String s) {
    System.out.println( "Function Name" );
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    CGraph g = new CGraph("entry");

    g.enterBF(new CGVisitor() {
        @Override
        public void nodeOperations(CGraph graph, CGraphNode currentNode) {
            System.out.println("20");
        }

        @Override
        public String getString() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No string can be returned from this anonymous implementation of CGVisitor.");
        }
    });

    a( 11 );
  }

  public static void a(int n) {
    b( n );
  }

  public static void b(int m) {
    int n;

    if (m >= 10)
      a( m-1 );
    else
      System.out.println(m);
  }
}
```

I double checked that the `visitMethod` method above is always executed, returns a non-null instance of `InvokeFinder`and that this instance never happens to be executed; how is it possible that under these conditions `InvokeFinder.visitMethodInsn` is never called by the ClassReader, even if there are invocation instruction in some methods of `MyTestClass` (e.g. inside method `a(int)`)?

EDIT: Going further with the debugging, i found out that ClassReader calls the default `MethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn` instead of calling the overridden version `InvokeFinder.visitMethodInsn`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that i changed API version of ASM and the signature of `MethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn` is different between versions 4 and 5. The dynamic binding no longer recognized it as an overriding method.

I could fix this by adding the missing parameters to `InvokeFinder.visitMethodInsn`, whose signature now is

```
public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc, boolean itf)
```